# ProgressBar not updating using a For Each loop

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I'm copying all the .avi and .png files from one folder into another:

```
Private Sub CopierSend_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopierSend_Button.Click

    If MessageBox.Show("Click OK to send media or just Cancel.", "Media Copier", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.avi", "*.png")
            Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, DestFolder_ & foundFileInfo.Name, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        Next
    Else
        'Nothing Yet
    End If

End Sub
```

I want to add a `ProgressBar` which will count every time a file is copied, so I added this code before the `For Each` loop:

```
Dim file1() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, "*.avi")
Dim file2() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, "*.png")
Dim files = file1.Length + file2.Length
Copier_ProgressBar.Step = 1
Copier_ProgressBar.Maximum = files
```

And added this code inside the `For Each` loop:

```
Copier_ProgressBar.Value += 1
```

Here is all of my code:

```
Private Sub CopierSend_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopierSend_Button.Click

    If MessageBox.Show("Click OK to send media or just Cancel.", "Media Copier", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim file1() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, "*.avi")
        Dim file2() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, "*.png")
        Dim files = file1.Length + file2.Length
        Copier_ProgressBar.Step = 1
        Copier_ProgressBar.Maximum = files

        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.avi", "*.png")
            Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, DestFolder_ & foundFileInfo.Name, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
            Copier_ProgressBar.Value += 1
        Next

    Else

        'Nothing Yet

    End If
End Sub
```

The `ProgressBar` updates, but only after all the files have been copied instead of updating in real time. Any idea?

Comment: @Bugs : In some way your answer was really helpful to make me understand how a BackgroundWorker can work, but unfortunately, your example didn't work for me at all. I am not saying that is wrong... Maybe something is missing or something I missing!!! I am testing some things... This is why I didn't give any answer yet. Really thank you for your time anyway!!!

Comment: Hm strange, I did test before posting on some sample files and it did work. Can you debug and see if the `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` method is called? Quite easily done; place a breakpoint here `BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` and press F11 to step through the code. It should step into `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork`. It could be an error in there?

Comment: I used your code into a new, blank project and working perfectly. So, something is wrong with my code into the main project. Thank you very much for your help my friend!!!

Comment: Not a problem, hope you find out what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands it looks like the `ProgressBar` doesn't do anything until *after* all the files have copied. That isn't strictly true. Instead your UI is not updating.

Instead you should look into using a [BackgroundWoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to report progress. Something like this should do the trick:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'This can also be set using the Designer
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True

End Sub

Private Sub CopierSend_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopierSend_Button.Click

    If MessageBox.Show("Click OK to send media or just Cancel.", "Media Copier", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim file1() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, "*.avi")
        Dim file2() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, "*.png")
        Dim files As Integer = file1.Length + file2.Length

        Copier_ProgressBar.Step = 1
        Copier_ProgressBar.Maximum = files       

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(FrapsFolder_, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.avi", "*.png")
        Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, DestFolder_ & foundFileInfo.Name, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Copier_ProgressBar.Value + 1)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    Copier_ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub
```

As an additional note, for best practice, I would consider using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of concatenating strings together:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, Path.Combine(DestFolder_, foundFileInfo.Name), Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```